# Why is the speed of light being invariant and finite in all inertial reference frames?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, relativity

I understand the basics of Lorentz transformation and Riemann Geometry but I still cannot understand why the speed of light is the same in all inertial references. Has anyone ever researched about this?

Comment: "*Has anyone ever researched about this?*" Shirley you can't be serious...

Comment: "Why...?" is not a useful kind of question in science. "How...?" questions are the only ones that are truly accessible to the scientific method. Having said that, there is no microscopic theory that could answer "How does spacetime acquire its Lorentz symmetry?", which is the closest one can probably get to what you are asking. There is undoubtedly such a theory, but we are nowhere close to guessing it, yet. The problem is not theoretical, though, but experimental. Nature hasn't given us any clues, yet.

Comment: If you view SR from a 4D point of view, pretty well everything becomes obvious concerning light invariance.  See http://goo.gl/fz4R0I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the theory of [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) this is postulated. Hence the theory does not address *why* this is true. If you're wondering why special relativity postulates this, the simple answer is that these are arguably the simplest postulates that give a theory that explains observed phenomena. You may want to read about the [history of special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_special_relativity) to better understand what discoveries and competing theories led up to the formulation of this theory.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about. Is there any reason behind this postulate (either in quantum gravity)? As you mentioned "the simple answer is that these are arguably the simplest postulates that give a theory that explains observed phenomena." -> I am just purely curious

Comment: You did not (try to) answer the question though. Why is the speed of light invariant?